# Android code to boot device without press any power button?

Tags: android, boot, reboot

Is it possible to boot the device when the battery is already inserted, and then main power is connected, without the help of any power switches?

Is there any ADB command to boot up the device after completely turned off?

Please keep in mind: I am not asking for reboot, I'll ask for boot after switched off.

Comment: *Is there any Adb command to boot up the device after completely turned off ??* **no**

Comment: I don't think it's possible, if you switch off your device, it will be disconnected from adb, so no adb commands will work.

Comment: you can put some devices into fastboot mode (sometimes its volume down + connect usb cable), in that case you could use `fastboot reboot` to boot the device. Anyways, this question is not really programming related, try to ask it on [android.se]

Comment: "Is it possible to boot the device..." -- ask the device manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any Adb command to boot up the device after completely turned
>   off ??

No.

Perhaps it would help to understand that an app runs. For an app to run it needs a processor/cpu to process the commands. If a processor (cpu) has no power then it can;t process anything. Therefore the app needs power. If there is no power then the app can't run. If it can't run then it can't switch the phone on!!!!!!!

Really quite simple when you think about it.

The closest you will get is to set an alarm to wake up the system if it goes into hibernation/sleep mode

Comment: then, is there any way to change system files to make it possible??

Comment: @khushhalgoyal No. If there is no power then the system is not running, There is no processor capable of functioning without power!

Comment: but after plugin charger, device will goes in charging mode, then, we have to do something in system files to boot up device automatically without pressing power button. but i don't have any idea how to do it,

Comment: @khushhalgoyal You have no idea how to do it because it can't be done!

Comment: thnx for ur coperation

Answer (score 1):

Hold the volume + & volume - and plug the usb cable into your device while its plugged into your PC, the phone should enter fastboot mode. Make sure you have adb and fastboot installed on your PC, open the platform tools folder that is in your PCs C: drive, hold the shift key on your keyboard and right click on an empty spot in the folder and open a command window. Run the following command: fastboot reboot